# Limiting records in a random select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I've searched all over and can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere so I'm asking for help.

I'm trying to randomly select 5 people. Kind of like a drawing. Everyone can enter themselves however many times they want to enter but only 3 of those entries can be considered. So... 5 distinct people will win, but all the entries (dups included) need to be considered up to 3 entries.

For example:

```
Adam,1
Adam,2
Adam,1
Adam,1
Sally,2
Timmy,3
John,1
John,1
Jenny,2
Wendy,3
Wendy,3
Wendy,3
Wendy,5
Wendy,5
```

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
select top 5 
    name, vote 
from 
    (SELECT 
         name, vote 
     FROM 
         Entries 
     GROUP BY 
          name, vote) winners 
ORDER BY
    NEWID();
```

My problem is (1) I'm not limiting them to 3 per for consideration cause I'm blanking on how to do that and (2) Distinct isn't working because they could enter themselves 100 times and have voted on a different entry each time.

Comment: What's `vote` represent?

Comment: For the problem of people having more than one user record, there is no solution.  You can work on the ounce of prevention, but that will reduce the scope of the problem.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2000

Comment: @user3361687 Can you explain what `vote` represents?  You're grouping by both name and vote, is it "Wendy" who has 3 entries to win even though she's in their 5 times, or does "Wendy,5" have 2 chances to win becaue she's in their 2 times?

Comment: Why do you use retired product which is 14 years old?

Comment: Votes are irrelevant. It's what she wants as a prize if she wins. All 5 of her entries would be counted. Her votes have no baring on her winning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It will only include up to three entries per name.

```
WITH UpToThree AS
(
    SELECT
         Name
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Vote)
        ,NEWID() as RandID
    FROM
        Entries
)
SELECT TOP 5
    Name, MAX(RandID)
FROM
    UpToThree
WHERE
    RN < 4
GROUP BY
    Name
ORDER BY
    MAX(RandID)
```

Comment: But this will bias the contestants votes - In the case of Wendy, her "5" votes won't be considered as her first three votes were "3".

Comment: This doesn't stop the same person from being selected multiple times.

Comment: @user2864740 I didn't get that this is a vote count in the vote column.  If it is then this table has other issues...

Comment: Now it's broken.  Can't order by `NEWID()` without selecting `NEWID()` when using `DISTINCT`.

Comment: The votes don't matter. I'm just displaying them in my list of winners. :)

Comment: @JNK . . . Clever solution.  However, I don't think that taking the max of a random number is going to give a person with three entries three times the likelihood of winning as someone with one entry.  It will give them a better likelihood, but I don't think it is linear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if any of the following are unavailable in SQL 2000:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Name
FROM (SELECT Name,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) nid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY NEWID()) RN
      FROM Table1) as sub
WHERE RN <= 3
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY MAX(nid)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98b252/17/0)

I'm not sure how you want to decide which vote you want to display, but that should be handled in a separate join to the winners list if you want the entries to be considered on virtue of name alone.

Comment: Yeah... I'm getting 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name. I'm seeing I can do the same with temporary tables though. I'll investigate. This just may not be a possible query to write. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I see a challenge in ensuring that the people with 3 entries are 3 times more likely to win than people with 1 entry.  I am assuming that `votes` is not important, because it is not mentioned in the question or comments.

The strategy is to first limit the entries to 3 per person randomly using `row_number()` (and a `where`).  Then, order the results again and enumerate each row using `row_number()` randomly.  By enumerating randomly, any entry has an equal change of being at the top -- so a person with 3 entries has three times the probability of being the best as someone with one entry.

Finally, choose the first five people based on this sequence number:

```
with entries_3 as (
      select e.*
      from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by newid()) as seqnum
            from entries
           ) e
      where seqnum <= 3
     ),
     entries_3_ordered (
      select e.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum2
      from entries_3
     )
select top 5 name, votes
from from entries_3_ordered
group by name, votes
order by min(seqnum2);
```